# Is there a clean way to parallelize multi-index tables?

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization

The documentation of [`ParallelTable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelTable.html) indicates that if you want to parallelize the evaluation of a table of more than one dimension, such as

```
Table[f[i,j], {i, 5}, {j, 5}]
```

it is often not enough to simply use `ParallelTable`, as this will in general only parallelize over the outermost index.

> Parallelization happens along the outermost (first) index:
>
> ```
> ParallelTable[Labeled[Framed[f[i, j]], $KernelID], {i, 4}, {j, i}]
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> ---
>
> Using multiple iteration specifications is equivalent to nesting Table functions:
>
> ```
> ParallelTable[i + j, {i, 3}, {j, i}]
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> ```
> ParallelTable[Table[i + j, {j, i}], {i, 3}]
> ```
>
> [image]

In some use cases (such as a relatively long computation to be run for a limited number of instances, say this five by five array, with more cores than each dimension, say eight kernels) this can be a significant under-use of system resources.

This can be overcome by joining the two indices into one multi-index and parallelizing over that, in the form

```
ParallelTable[
  With[{i=index[[1]], j=index[[2]]},
    f[i,j]
  ],
{index, Flatten[Array[List, {5, 5}], 1] }]
```

but this feels like a bad hack.

Is there a cleaner way to make `ParallelTable` throw those bounds to the wind and simply hand out computation to any kernel that's free for it?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem today and was unpleasantly surprised about this functionality of `ParallelTable`. The `Method->"FinestGrained"` does not wokr as one would naively expect due to the parallelization over the outermost index only. I came up the following solution.

```
ClearAll[NonNestedParallelTable];
NonNestedParallelTable[a_,b__][balance_:Identity,opts___]:=Module[{args,res,idxs,i,rule},
    args={b}[[All,1]];
    res=Table[Unique[]->args,b];
    idxs=Flatten[res]//balance;
    res=res/.Rule[x_,y_]:>x;
    res/.ParallelTable[i[[1]]->Inactive[With][MapThread[Inactive[Set][#1,#2]&,{args,i[[2]]}],Hold[a]] // Activate // ReleaseHold,{i,idxs}]
]
NonNestedParallelTable//Attributes={HoldFirst};
```

The main idea is to flatten out the table before computation and reconstruct the non-flat table by means of unique identifier. The `opts`-argument can be used to pass options to the flat `ParallelTable` inside the module and the `balance`-argument can be used to manipulate evaluation order manually. This implementation should work on non-regular arrays of arbitrary dimension. Here an example using three parallel kernels

> ```
> NonNestedParallelTable[{$KernelID, f[i, j]}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 3}][]//MatrixForm
> ```
>
> [image]

> ```
> ParallelTable[{$KernelID, f[i, j]}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 3}] // MatrixForm
> ```
>
> [image]

where we clearly see that `ParallelTable` does not utilize all kernels while `NonNestedParallelTable` does. Using the `balance`-argument of `NonNestedParallelTable` one can affect the evaluation order manually:

> ```
> NonNestedParallelTable[{$KernelID, f[i, j]}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 3}][]//MatrixForm
> ```

> ```
> NonNestedParallelTable[{$KernelID, f[i, j]}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 3}][Reverse]//MatrixForm
> ```

> ```
> NonNestedParallelTable[{$KernelID, f[i, j]}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 3}][(RandomSample[#, Length[#]] &)] // MatrixForm
> ```

> [image]

Using `(RandomSample[#, Length[#]] &)` could be used as a naive load balancing method in case of significantly differing computation times for `f[i,j]`.

**One disclaimer:** I have not tested the implementation of `NonNestedParallelTable` to my satisfaction and I can not guarantee that it works for all functions and ranges. I will start using the method for my parallel computations/tables and will report (and hopefully fix) errors should I encounter some.